# Problems with flipping cards (vanilla JS)

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to solve 2 problems with [this project](https://codepen.io/squinter/pen/vQeERq):

1. Flip the cards back when no match is made.
2. Once the randomization occurs, allow the user to briefly show all the randomized cards for x seconds before the game timer commences.

At one point I was able to flip the unmatched cards, but I lost that ability whilst trying to sort out problem #2.

For #1 I first declared a variable:

```
const pix = document.querySelectorAll('.card img');
```

Then I did an if/else to hide unmatched:

```
function checkForMatch() {
  if (
      toggledCards[0].firstElementChild.className === toggledCards[1].firstElementChild.className) {
        toggledCards[0].classList.toggle('match');
        toggledCards[1].classList.toggle('match');
        toggledCards = [];
        matched++;
      }  else {
          setTimeout(() => {
          toggleCard(toggledCards[0]);
          toggleCard(toggledCards[1]);
          toggledCards = [];
          // Trying to hide unmatchaed cards here
          pix.style.display = "none";
        }, 1000);
      }
  };
```

That fails and I cannot figure out why.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand what you're asking. Where exactly is the code failing? `toggledCards[0].firstElementChild` should be your image element? I did a quick inspect and I'm not seeing any classes on your images, so that could be an issue.

Comment: Isn't 'card' the class within which the images exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Sheng Slogar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2535504/sheng-slogar) have mentioned, You don't have class names on your `img` tags so it doesn't work. I added some to check and it was working, so just add classes with numbers to images and it will work properly :)

I also recommend to use `data attributes` for this kind of functionality as it's exactly what they are made for.